# Webshim: Initialization for a specific FormID

Tags: webshim

How can I initialize webshim only for a specific formID?

webshim.polyfill('#formID forms forms-ext');

Comment: Hi John and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide more context about what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey @dovetalk, another idea ...
`$('#formID').webshim.polyfill('forms forms-ext');`

But I think there is no way.